# Converting complicated string to array

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsarray

I have a string as follow

```
[["3254","CCH"],["001","Sulmatyl 50mg","Sulpiride",[0,0,0,0,1],28,0.5],["002","Knowful 1.2g","Piracetam",[1,0,0,0,0],28,1],["003",Tranexamic acid 250mg","Tranexamic acid",[0,3,3,3,0],7,1],["004","Isormol 20mg","Isosorbide mononitrate",[0,3,0,3,0],28,0.5],["005","Plavix 75mg","Clopidogrel",[1,0,0,0,0],28,1]]
```

How can I convert this string into an array?
So it will be like

```
[

["3254","CCH"],  // pres[0]
["001","Sulmatyl 50mg","Sulpiride",[0,0,0,0,1],28,0.5], //pres[1]
["002","Knowful 1.2g","Piracetam",[1,0,0,0,0],28,1], //pres[2]
["003",Tranexamic acid 250mg","Tranexamic acid",[0,3,3,3,0],7,1], //pres[3]
["004","Isormol 20mg","Isosorbide mononitrate",[0,3,0,3,0],28,0.5], //pres[4]
["005","Plavix 75mg","Clopidogrel",[1,0,0,0,0],28,1] //pres[5]

]
```

Comment: Give an example of which type of array you want. Thats will help other to solve your problem.

Comment: just edited it!! thank you!

Comment: Let me know how you get this string? From a json response or any other way.

Comment: It seems that the string missed one character '"' at  ["003",Tranexamic...

Comment: It must be ["003","Tranexamic..., if it is JSON

Comment: do you have a string, or do you like to construct an array from this string literal in your source code?

Comment: _"complicated string"_...?! do you mean JSON, maybe?

Comment: i got the string from QR code and would like to make the string into an array

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at very low-level and complicated parsing, however converting `[` to `(` and `]` to `)` and parsing as JSON would mostly work:

```
let newString = inputString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "(", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
let newString = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: ")", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
let data = newString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
do {
    let rootObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
    // done 
} catch {
    print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

For best results, however, serialise using XML or JSON and avoid bespoke formats unless you are willing to put the work in to parse them.